# Laravel - как хранить константы?

Tags: laravel

Как лучше хранить константы? 
Желательно так, чтобы обращаться к ним можно было бы просто по имени

Comment: А тебе глобальные константы нужны? тогда я думаю лучше храни их в фале конфига и обращайся к ним через `config('app.my_const')`

Comment: помогло, только сделал в своём отдельном файле конфига и обращаюсь так: 
config('myconfigfile.my_const.my_const_value1')

в конфиге выглядит так:
myconfigfile.php:
[
    my_const => [
        my_const_value1 => 1,
        my_const_vslue2 => 2,
    ]
]